# Aggregate by certain characteristic in Mule using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, xslt-2.0, mule-studio

I'm using Mule to pull info from a database and format it like this -

```
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <color>blue</color>
    <city>Chicago</city>
</item>
```

There are several records like this with id as the primary key, so I have several of these records, each in a different MuleMessage. I want to group by group_id so each of my MuleMessages look like this -

```
<item>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
    <id>3</id>
</item>
```

I know I have to group the messages by an aggregator, but I'm not sure how to put group_id as the aggregating attribute. Would I need to use a XSLT transformer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting this input file

```
<items>
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <color>blue</color>
    <city>Chicago</city>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <color>red</color>
    <city>Chicago</city>
</item>
<item>
    <id>3</id>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <color>yellow</color>
    <city>Detroit</city>
</item>
<item>
    <id>4</id>
    <group_id>2</group_id>
    <color>cyan</color>
    <city>Washington</city>
</item>
<item>
    <id>5</id>
    <group_id>2</group_id>
    <color>gray</color>
    <city>Colorado</city>
</item>
</items>
```

this xslt could make output you need

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="items" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="group_id">
        <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:element name="group_id">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </xsl:element>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:element name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<item>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
    <id>3</id>
</item>
<item>
    <group_id>2</group_id>
    <id>4</id>
    <id>5</id>
</item>
```

Edit: if you have not one input file with all items but more files with single item, you could do it by something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="files" select="collection('file:///path/to/files/item*.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="items">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$files/item" group-by="group_id">
            <xsl:element name="item">
                <xsl:element name="group_id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:element name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```